# How to update a list item date/time field, programmatically with formated datatime

Tags: sharepoint, datetime, formatting, listitem

> The date format is like this.
>
> 0001-01-01T00:00:00 -> not updating.
>   2012-05-21T00:00:00 -> updating properly

Following code I used.

```
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPWeb subsite = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList englist = subsite.Lists["list"];

    SPListItem item1 = englist.Items.Add();
    item1["Title"] = "title";
    item1["date"] = "0001-01-01T00:00:00";//0001-01-01T00:00:00 -> not updating. 2012-05-21T00:00:00
    item1.Update();
    Console.WriteLine("Added");
```

What is the reason the date time value "0001-01-01T00:00:00" not updating.

I find this might be ths issue( date range limitation)

[image]

Comment: I find that sharepoint datetime field type support date range of 1/1/1900 and 12/31/8900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint using MSSQL for storing values of the fields, so DateTime field mapped to [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) sql type which have range from January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999. That is the reason why can not store such small values in database.

Comment: Raange is between /1/1900 and 12/31/8900 i think.

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan you can look into msdn using the link, there you'll find all information about MSSQL datetime, including value range

Comment: I have seen that. But have u tried to add values like ""0001-01-01T00:00:00" u will get one message in new item form like the range is between " /1/1900 and 12/31/8900" is accepted. thanks